# adding text to python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey guys I am doing a sample project on python. I have made a simple calculator. The thing is that I want that calculator in a box. I have read many articles and I found about `Tkinter`.

The thing is I want to get the input as a text using tkinter.

My code

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

my_text = tk.Text(root)

my_text.pack()

my_text.insert(tk.END,"Select operation.")
```

When i run `my_text.insert(tk.END,"Select operation.")` it works fine in a box but when i run `my_text.insert(input(tk.END,"Enter choice(1/2/3/4")):` it doesn't work ..

Why is it so. I need `Enter choice(1/2/3/4")):` to be printed on the screen with box.

Hope you can find a solution for me ..Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you should check out [Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget.

Comment: thats doesnt have any purpose here ??

Comment: the thing is that i want enter choice text to be displayed in a box with input function

Comment: I believe the first comment is what you are looking for. I think you can use a `StringVar` to have a prompt inside the entry box if I can remember right.

Comment: i have used string var but it didnt solved my prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `input` with a text widget. You will need to create buttons or bindings that react to events. You should work through a complete Tkinter tutorial so you can understand how it works.

Comment: so you say i need to use buttons for my purpose ?